# Difference between a = [undefined] and a = new Array(1)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

```
var a = [undefined, undefined];
var b = new Array(2);

0 in a // returns true
1 in a // returns true
0 in b // returns false
1 in b // returns false
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = new Array(2);
```

just says that, `b` is an array of size two. But the array is just empty. It doesn't have any elements in it. So, there are no indexes as such. So, `0` and `1` are not yet there in `b`. These are called holes.

But, when you say

```
var a = [undefined, undefined];
```

you are creating an array with two elements in it. So, it has `undefined` at index `0` and `1`. That is why they both exist in the array.

---

**Note:** When you simply assign a value to a variable, without declaring it with `var` (`let` or `const`), it will become a global variable.

Comment: In your note, you forgot to talk about strict mode! @Rohit Please always use strict mode!